# MySQL Query for fetching multiple distinct values

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

```
id  qid answer  date                    answer_userKey
72  2   2       2012-07-30 00:00:00     1
71  1   4       2012-07-30 00:00:00     1
70  2   2       2012-07-30 00:00:00     2
69  1   4       2012-07-30 00:00:00     2
68  2   2       2012-07-30 00:00:00     3
67  1   3       2012-07-30 00:00:00     3
66  2   2       2012-07-31 00:00:00     4
65  1   4       2012-07-31 00:00:00     4
64  2   2       2012-07-31 00:00:00     5
```

Here's my sample table, I need to get all data + all distinct  answer_userKeys for every date like this

```
date           DISTINCT(answer_userKey)
2012-07-30     3
2012-07-31     2
```

As well as all the single values in a normal associative array like you get when you do

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_data 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-07-29' AND '2012-08-01'
```

Tried everything here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(date) dte, COUNT(DISTINCT answer_userKey) cnt
FROM tbl_data 
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2012-07-29' AND '2012-08-01'
GROUP BY dte;
```

Comment: Solved it :) Just added *, before the DATE(date) and everything worked as a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is your requirement..this one works in oracle

```
select to_char(date,'yyyy-mm-dd') date
      ,count(distinct answer_userKey) DISTINCT(answer_userKey) 
from table_name 
group by to_char(date,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need both the detail and aggregate data, then you will likely either need to perform two queries to get these two different sets of data, or simply query the details and build the aggregation within whatever language you are using (perhaps in a multidimensional array).  For example in pseudo-code:

```
Query: SELECT * FROM tbl_data WHERE date BETWEEN '?' AND '?'

array; // multidimensional associative array to be populated
while ([fetch next row from result set as row] ) {
    array[row['date']][row['answer_userKey']] = row
}
```